# GoogleSignIn.h cannot be found

Tags: swift, cocoapods, google-signin

I have a project with GoogleSignIn implemented. I haven't worked on the project in a while (since before Xcode 9 or maybe even 8), and now it's not building because "GoogleSignIn.h cannot be found" in the project bridging header file.

Google Sign-in had been working before, which I would think means I created the project bridging header correctly. (and as you'll see in the podfile I did change `Google/SignIn` to `GoogleSignIn` or whatever that change was). And `GoogleSignIn.h` does appear to be in the workspace! It's right there in `Pods(project)/Pods(folder)/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GooleSignIn.framework/Headers/GoogleSignIn.h` and it reads thus:

```
#import "GIDAuthentication.h"
#import "GIDGoogleUser.h"
#import "GIDProfileData.h"
#import "GIDSignIn.h"
#import "GIDSignInButton.h"
```

Since returning to the project, I've used `pod deintegrate` and `pod clean` (and of course `pod install`) to remove some Facebook pods (which had been causing some build problems) and Firebase pods (which created some thread warnings), and change from Google/SignIn`to`GoogleSignIn` (or whatever that change was) and my podfile currently reads thus:

```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Your Song' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Your Song
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'RealmSearchViewController'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  target 'Your SongTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'RealmSearchViewController'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'KIF'
    pod 'Nimble'
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
    end
  end
end
```

Why isn't it seeing `GoogleSignIn.h`? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Google's docs say your bridging header should say `#import <Google/SignIn.h>`, not `GoogleSignIn.h`

Comment: Thanks but I did try that as well, with the same problem.